# How to record a log whenever someone tries to copy any file from a specific folder in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, logging, file-copying

I have one folder support `imp` it contains very sensitive files. So What I wanted to do is that whenever someone tries to copy any file from this folder to any other location, I just wanted to record a log for this operation, So later I can found which user has done that.
I am using `logging` module of python to record the logs. Please tell me how can I record this activity.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @shrewmouse I am using ```ubuntu``` but my application will be running on multiple platform

Answer (score 0):

Most modern Desktop OSs provide some kind of API for monitoring file system events - On Linux, it's called `inotify` and Windows has a .NET API class called `FileSystemWatcher`. I'm not sure of the counterparts for MacOS.

There are a few Python libraries that can abstract this out for you and automatically use the correct API depending on the OS you are using.

For example, check out the [Watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/) library which works across multiple platforms.

Or if you're on Linux you can also use [this inotify adapter](https://pypi.org/project/inotify/)

Comment: I am using ```ubuntu```, I tried ```watchdog``` but it don't keep track when any file from the current folder is copied to other location. I want some library which will be cross platform. As my application will be running in all major platforms.